# Get the printed length of a string in terminal

Tags: python, bash, string-length

It seems like a fairly simple task, yet I can't find a fast and reliable solution to it.

I have strings in bash, and I want to know the number of characters that will be printed on the terminal. The reason I need this, is to nicely align the strings in three columns of `n` characters each. For that, I need to add as many "space" as necessary to make sure the second and third columns always starts at the same location in the terminal.

Example of problematic string length:

```bash
v='féé'

echo "${#v1}"
 > # 5 (should be 3)

printf '%s' "${v1}" | wc -m
 > # 5 (should be 3)

printf '%s' "${v1}" | awk '{print length}'
 > # 5 (should be 3)
```

The best I have found is this, that works *most of the time*.

```bash
echo "${v}" | python3 -c 'v=input();print(len(v))'
 > # 3 (yeah!)
```

But sometimes, I have characters that are modified by the following sequences. I can't copy/past that here, but this is how it looks like:

```bash
v="de\314\201tresse"
echo "${v}"
 > # détresse
echo "${v}" | python3 -c 'v=input();print(len(v))'
 > # 9 (should be 8)
```

I know it can be even more complicated with `\r` character or ANSI sequences, but I am only going to have to deal with "regular" strings that can be commonly found in filenames, documents and other file content writing by humans. Since the string IS printed in the terminal, I guess there must be some engine that knows or can know the printed length of the string.

I have also considered the possible solution of sending ANSI sequence to get the position of the cursor in the terminal before and after printing the string, and use the difference to compute the length, but it looks like a rabbit hole I don't want to dig. Plus it will be very slow.

Comment: I don;t know if this is contributing to your problems or not but be aware that `echo` will add a newline so the output of `echo 'foo'` is 4 characters long, not 3 as you might expect. You could use `printf '%s' 'foo'` instead but then the output is no longer a valid text "file" since it doesn't have a terminating newline so YMMV with what any text processing tool does with it so - read the man page for whatever tool you use to determine the length if you go that route rather than just subtracting 1.

Comment: @EdMorton But `input()` in Python removes the newline.

Comment: These should be helpful: [How can I get sensible results from len(), str.format() and a zero-width space?](/q/48342671/4518341), [How do I get the "visible" length of a combining Unicode string in Python?](/q/33351599/4518341)

Comment: Be careful what you ask. "Length of a string" does not mean "apparent number of occupied columns onscreen". The "length of a string" *maybe* means the "number of characters", but sometimes means the number of *bytes*, which is a very different thing. `féé` looks like three characters, but those `é`'s are not `e`'s. It takes two bytes to print that one character, though if you print out the individual bytes, one looks like an `e`, and the other doesn't generally print, since it's an "overstrike". Be super careful in your terminology - and I bet I botched mine here somewhere, lol. Tricky!

Comment: @PaulHodges yes I am interested in the number of columns that needs to be used to print a string in the terminal. Indeed, it does not correspond to the number of bytes, nor the number of characters (zero-width spaces for instance, although I really doubt I will ever have someone inserting this in filenames).

Comment: @Slagt to get the number of terminal cells needed for a string you'd need to use wcswidth.

Comment: @PaulHodges, I would take len() for a string as being the number of characters in a string, len() or a byte sequence as number of bytes required for the string given an encoding. Often, in my code I am  usually more interested in the number of extended grapheme clusters in the string. And as in this question, there are the number of terminal cells required for a string (wcwidth/wcswidth).

Comment: length is (5, 3, 7, 10, 12, 3), ie number of characters, number of graphemes, number of bytes (UTF-8), number of bytes (utf-16-le/be), number of bytes (utf-16), number of terminal cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
v='féé'
echo "${v}" | python3 -c 'import unicodedata as ud;v=input();print(len(ud.normalize("NFC",v)))'
```

If you have trouble installing with

```
pip install unicodedata
```

try unicodedata2

*Additional Notes*

This will normalize strings to utf-8 according to the NFC standard explained [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). If you are working with Latin ANSI, then it should work fine. However, for pre-Unicode ANSI encodings of languages such as Arabic, Greek, Hebrew, Russian or Thai, then NFC may keep the original formatting. Although it is generally more advisable to use NFC, you could try NFKC in those cases. The reason for preferring NFC is to avoid normalizing symbols that are compatible but not canonically equivalent, for example the single character ﬀ (U+FB00): if you normalize it with NFC, it is length 1, but if you normalize it with NFKC, that's length 2. Depending on your application that can create some issues, but if you just want readable text, then NFKC is fine.

Comment: You should note the limitations of this approach.

Comment: I will update it with some clarifications

Comment: NFKC seems to work just fine with Latin AINSI, is there a reason to prefer NFC?

Comment: I've added some explanation  about that. it's about unicode equivalence.

Comment: @LucasMouraGomes, you do not install `unicodedata` via pip, it is part of your Python install.

Comment: "This will normalize strings to utf-8" This has nothing to do with UTF-8. Depending on the code-points in the specific string Python will internally store it either as ISO-8859-1, UCS2, or UCS4, never UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of terminal cells used by a string, it is possible to use `wcswidth`. There is a Python implementation for `wcwidth` and `wcswidth`.

With Python install `wcwidth`:

```bash
pip install wcwidth
```

And the Python code would be:

```py
from wcwidth import wcswidth
v = 'féé'
print(wcswidth(v))
# 3
```

It will also yield the correct result for NFD:

```py
v = ud.normalize("NFD",v)
print(wcswidth(v))
# 3
```

Additionally it will correctly handle wide characters, i.e. characters that take up 2 terminal cells per character:

```py
v='中文'
print(wcswidth(v))
# 4
```

And adapting Lucas' solution above, for the terminal:

```
v='féé'
echo "${v}" | python3 -c 'from wcwidth import wcswidth;v=input();print(wcswidth(v))'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Perl`:

Without modules:

```
perl -CSAD -E 'say length($ARGV[0])' été
3
```

With `utf8::all` module:

```
perl -Mutf8::all -E 'say length($ARGV[0])' été
3
```

Comment: It does not look to work well with combined characters like in `de\314\201tresse` (output is 9, should be 8).

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `wc`:

```bash
$ v="de\314\201tresse"
$ printf "%s" "$v" | grep -o '[a-z]' | wc -l
8

$ v='féé'
$ printf "%s" "$v" | grep -o '[a-z]' | wc -l
3
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very simple solution without any additional tools. It does require to list all the "valid" characters though, one way or another `grep -i -o '[a-z0-9 +special characters]'`. I am not sure why [a-z] matches with `é` though, how is that an expected behavior?